# How can I join multiple animated objects into one object and keep the animation?

Tags: animation

I have a big problem with the development of my game. I've been working on a simple animation where a door would open and close. However, the door is more than just a door and a handle. It's more complex, with a working hinge and a box behind said door. The problem is that I want it as one single animation, instead of multiple objects having separate animations. I also need to keep this object joined so I can cook the texture into a UV map so I can transfer it to unreal. But I can't seem to figure out how to do the animations without having the hinge, door, handle, etc. attached together.

Comment: you can merge them, or parent them, or give them constraints...

Comment: If i were to add an armature, parent it to the door, then join the door with the rest of the objects, then the armature would not work anymore

Comment: If you don't want to join them you can try the alembic (abc) format to export. It works with Unreal.

Comment: I would still need it as a single animation

Comment: Why would you parent the armature to the door? The whole point of the armature is to control the door. The door will be the child of the armature, not the other way around. Creating an armature solves your problem, because when you animate after that, you're animating the armature, nothing else. This means potentially creating one single action as a result of all your animating efforts, which will mean only one animation existing in total, controlling every object the armature controls.